# improving database performance for a facebook style walling page

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, database-design, social-networking

This is about a social networking site. Let Facebook be our model.

there is a table in mysql server: 'posts' to keep precords of all the posts (excluding comments for simplicity). Its columns are:

id, post, user_id, frnd_id_1, frnd_id_2.

id: primary key , auto-incrementing.

post : post written on the wall (be it the wall of the logged in user or the one of any of his/her friends)

user_id: id of the logged in user (suppose A)

friend_id_1: friend (suppose B) of the logged-in user . this field is used when A writes on B's wall.

friend_id_2: friend (suppose C) of the friend of the logged-in user

if there is any message correspondence between A and B that is recorded in the mysql table acccordingly.

Suppose B writes something on C's wall then on the friends of B will see it in their individual wall. Suppose B has 100 friends. We could keep record of it in the said table in this manner: frnd_id_2 will be used to keep the recordof C's id;

If frind_2 has a '0' record , the message correspondence isonly between user_id and frnd_id_1, else it will mean frnd_id_1 has written on the wall of frnd_id_2 and frind_id_1 is a friend of user_id.

UP TO THIS , I THINK, EVERYTHING IS EXACTLY SIMILAR WITH FACEBOOK.

But -

Suppose B has 100 friends. In that case if B writes on C's wall (assume that all the privacy settings r open for friends of friends). If the aforementioned policy is taken, there will be 101 records in the table  :

1) One record just to mean that B has posted on C's wall (frnd_id_2=0) .(Let us call it the MAIN RECORD)

2) Another 100 records for the 100 friends of B. (frnd_id_2!=0)

This is the way I have in my brain. I could improve it a bit more by inserting into the 'post' column (or keeping 'post' column blank and creating another one namely 'main_record_id')not the full message, but the id of the main record.

But the thing is: For a single post, 101 db queries(in this case) need to be executed. Any other way to improve db performance?

I am using PHP as the scripting language.

Comment: why negative marking ? any explanation plz?

Comment: Misunderstood the question at first.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: can't u remove the -ve rating?

Comment: Now I don't think I want to.  There's no penalty to you, unless enough people agree with me that your question should be closed.  Stop worrying so much.

Answer (score 0):

Or 1 database query that brings back all the information in one network roundtrip.  I'd batch them into one JOIN query.

You can't get away with storing all those records if you intend to keep them, but you can control how you access them.

Another thought to keep in mind would be controlling the size of the result set returned.  Do you really need all 100 friends at the same time?  Could you do as well with ten at a time?  This will become especially important when you have 1,000 or 10,000 records to return.

Comment: ' 1 database query that brings back all the information in one network roundtrip. I'd batch them into one JOIN query.' explain please as I can't understand. What tables to join? 'you do as well with ten at a time' - when to do with the remaining 90 records?

Comment: Google for SQL JOIN for the first one.  I'm assuming a one-to-many relationship between user and friends or user and posts.  What to do with the remaining 90 records?  First of all, write your query so you don't return them.  Second, provide the user with a "next 10" link so they can get records 11-20, 21-30, etc.

Comment: I know about SQL join. for all the users, posts in the wall are to be stored in a single table. So what tables to join? As to the 90 records, I am not talking about showing all the posts in the wall page at a time. Rather when B writes on C's wall, for the 100 firnds B has, 100 records need to be inserted into the db so that the 100 friends get themin their walls when they view walls. The 100-record-thing is npt about showing those up in the wall page

Comment: I think @duffymo tries to say instead of inserting 100 records, insert just one, and use join to show the posts in the wall according to your friends. In other words normalize the database

Comment: can u help regarding the normalization of the table stated here? What things should be done to normalize the db (inserting 101 queried) in this case?

Comment: @Darhazer, please have a look at my comment immediately before the last one of you.

Comment: Have you waited a whole week for someone to answer your question without doing anything about it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

A short answer: DO NOT USE MYSQL for facebook-like wall - it is very ineffective for such purpose.

Use no-sql database instead, MongoDB for example. I promise you'll be surprised how much more convenient it is for live newsfeeds with different kind of objects.

You can combine two DBs also: MongoDB for newsfeed and MySQL for everything else.